# Python Sorting Tie Breaking with ascending order and descending order

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, tuples

please help on this Sorting

```
 d={'d':1,'b':2,'c':3,'a':3}
```

what should i do to get out as ascending order by value and descending order by key.

ie

```
OUT=[('d', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 3)]
```

I know  `a=sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:(x[1],-x[0]))` wont work since it is alphabet and will work fine if it is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ord`

**Ex:**

```
d={'d':1,'b':2,'c':3,'a':3}
a=sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:(x[1],-ord(x[0])))
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[('d', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 3)]
```